# How is the canonical morphism $V \times_U W \to X \times_S Y$ an open immersion?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, solution-verification, definition, schemes

**I don't see where in this proof below, [(from Stacks project)](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01JR), it is shown that $V \times_U W \to X \times_S Y$ is an open immersion.**

---

> [image]

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3686130/some-questions-on-the-inverse-image-of-open-set-appeared-in-the-fibre-product-of/3686168#3686168).

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $p^{-1}(V) \cap q^{-1}(W) \to X \times_S Y$ is an open immersion. By the uniqueness of fiber products one has $p^{-1}(V) \cap q^{-1}(W) \cong V \times_U W$, and the two maps $p^{-1}(V) \cap q^{-1}(W) \to X \times_S Y$ and $V \times_U W \to X \times_S Y$ are the same under that identification. Hence also $V \times_U  W \to X \times_S Y$ is an open immersion.